# How can I prevent multiple instances of a Timer running simultaneously inside Django?

Tags: python, django, timer

I'd like a method in my Django application to be invoked periodically every 60 seconds. It's a very simple task and I thought I'd use a `Timer`. Here's my code and it resides in the `__init__.py` of one of my apps:

```
from threading import Timer

def hello():
    print "xxx"
    Timer(60, hello).start()

Timer(60, hello).start()
```

This code gets invoked when Django imports my app.

This seems to work fine by when I've executed the `runserver` command, two instances of this start to run it seems because I keep seeing two lines of console output, every 60 seconds. I think this is because the run server command, runs multiple processes/thread, am I correct?

How can I ensure that only instance of the timer runs at a time?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to run code periodically is to set up a cron job that runs a django command.
You should set the cron job for the www-data user if running under apache (or in the `runserver` case probably your own user if you are in development mode)  This will ensure that the code is executed with the same permissions and ownerships as the web code.

You can also use [django-cron](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/) to make things easier (especially if running under windows)